# Table rendering in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/uwUMgg?p=preview

Initially, there are 3 lines of data, everything looks good, but after I click the add button to add one more line of data, the screen is messed up. below is the screenshot from firefox.

Can anyone help with this?

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: I looks fine to me on Chrome: http://screencast.com/t/zd1q7l0zY btw, the plunker that you shared has a small error on line 71 and won't work until you remove the `each` from the line

Comment: thanks guys, I still have no luck on 2 computers using FF

Answer (score 0):

tag table is not an actual table. when the directive gets rendered it calculates the width taking into account both the headers and the data. apparently once it gets updated it doesn't do it correctly at least not in FF.
if i where to quick and dirty solve this problem would wrap the table directive in other one that watches the model and re renders the table directive on every change. that if you don't want to use other directive. Which by the way thats what i would do, look for an alternative.